# recorrer array o matriz en javascript

Tags: javascript, php, array, matriz

pase un array de php a javascript con **json_encode** y luego **JSON.parse** el array en php me lo genera chevere sin problema e incluso lo recorro con el foreach igual sin  problema, pero necesito recorrerlo en javascript y no lo logro, cuando lo tengo en javascript y lo muestro con  **console.log(result_consult);** me muestra lo siguiente:

```
[{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7410,"idurb":0,"idtipo_com":7,"idcate":38,"idsubcat":163,"idsubcat_final":152,"idult_cat":57,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Valencia","provincias":"","zona_urb":"","categoria":"celulares y teléfonos","subcategoria":"apple","subcategoria_final":"iphone","ultima_categoria":"iphone 12 pro max","tipo_comercio":"celulares y teléfonos"},{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7410,"idurb":0,"idtipo_com":2,"idcate":92,"idsubcat":420,"idsubcat_final":0,"idult_cat":0,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Valencia","provincias":"","zona_urb":"","categoria":"cursos y clases","subcategoria":"ocio y tiempo libre","subcategoria_final":"","ultima_categoria":"","tipo_comercio":"servicios"},{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7417,"idurb":0,"idtipo_com":3,"idcate":244,"idsubcat":1104,"idsubcat_final":0,"idult_cat":0,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Los Guayos","provincias":"","zona_urb":"","categoria":"casas o townhouses","subcategoria":"venta","subcategoria_final":"","ultima_categoria":"","tipo_comercio":"inmobiliarias"},{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7410,"idurb":0,"idtipo_com":4,"idcate":28,"idsubcat":2410,"idsubcat_final":6176,"idult_cat":5623,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Valencia","provincias":"","zona_urb":"","categoria":"Carros, Motos y Otros","subcategoria":"carros y camionetas","subcategoria_final":"chery","ultima_categoria":"chery qq","tipo_comercio":"concesionarios"},{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7410,"idurb":0,"idtipo_com":4,"idcate":28,"idsubcat":2410,"idsubcat_final":6176,"idult_cat":5623,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Valencia","provincias":"","zona_urb":"","categoria":"Carros, Motos y Otros","subcategoria":"carros y camionetas","subcategoria_final":"chery","ultima_categoria":"chery qq","tipo_comercio":"concesionarios"},{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7410,"idurb":0,"idtipo_com":4,"idcate":28,"idsubcat":2410,"idsubcat_final":6176,"idult_cat":5623,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Valencia","provincias":"","zona_urb":"","categoria":"Carros, Motos y Otros","subcategoria":"carros y camionetas","subcategoria_final":"chery","ultima_categoria":"chery qq","tipo_comercio":"concesionarios"},{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7410,"idurb":8,"idtipo_com":3,"idcate":244,"idsubcat":1104,"idsubcat_final":0,"idult_cat":0,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Valencia","provincias":"","zona_urb":"Borrar","categoria":"casas o townhouses","subcategoria":"venta","subcategoria_final":"","ultima_categoria":"","tipo_comercio":"inmobiliarias"},{"idpa":13,"iddep":178,"idpro":0,"idmuni":7410,"idurb":0,"idtipo_com":13,"idcate":299,"idsubcat":0,"idsubcat_final":0,"idult_cat":0,"pais":"Venezuela","departamento":"Carabobo ","municipios":"Valencia","provincias":"","zona_urb":"","categoria":"hamburguesas","subcategoria":"","subcategoria_final":"","ultima_categoria":"","tipo_comercio":"comida rápida"}]
```

ahora lo que necesito es recorrerlo como hacia en php pero no encuentro manera, soy nuevo en esto, por acá le dejo el código php como lo recorría sin problema.

```
            foreach ($result_array_consult as $item){
                              
                if ($item[$array_pais_categ_disp_idpais]==$Idpais_select){
            
                  echo "<option value=$item[$array_pais_categ_disp_iddepartamento]>$item[$array_pais_categ_disp_departamento]</option>";                                
            
            }
            
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes iterar de muchas formas un array en javascript. usando el forEach quedaria algo asi.

```js
let data = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]

 data.forEach((item)=>{
    if(item.id ==2){
        console.log("Coincide con el segundo ")
    }

 })
```

Tambien puedes usar la notacion con "[]" te quedia asi

```js
let data = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]

 data.forEach((item)=>{
    if(item["id"] ==2){
        console.log("Coincide con el segundo ")
    }

 })
```

Comment: listo amigo  gracias por la ayuda con esa respuesta resolví, ahorita tengo otra con una nueva duda publicada .